# What is the difference between "der Rettich" and "das Radieschen"?

Tags: difference, noun

Both *Rettich* and *Radieschen* refer to *radish*.

- [Rettich](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=Rettich)
- [Radieschen](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=Radieschen)

Is there a difference? Is it a regional difference? Or different kind of raddish? Or is it just different names that refer to the same kind of generic radish?

Comment: The answer may depend on whether you are interested in botany terminology (then Radieschen are a subdivision of Rettich) or every-day use (then Radieschen are the little red radish turnips and Rettich is a larger white-ish radish turnip.)

Comment: Google Pictures would help a lot in this case.

Comment: @Chris: What's a radish turnip? I've never heard the term before and a quick Google search seems to turn up only pages comparing radishes and turnips...

Comment: @Mac: Hmm, I'm not a native English speaker. I assumed that "turnip" describes the bulb/tuber shape of the plant. The German word for "turnip" is "Rübe" and as far as I know "Rübe" is (1) a species by itself and (2) the term for thick edible roots. My assumption was that (2) is also true for English.

Comment: @Chris: Ah, ich beginne zu verstehen :) Ja, im Deutschen ist "Rübe" auch ein botanischer Begriff. Im Englischen heißt sowas je nach Kontext allerdings "root" oder "root vegetable". "Turnip" ist je nach geographischer Lage die Speise- oder die Steckrübe (die verschiedenen Rübenarten sind taxonomisch (sozusagen) ein sumpfiges Feld)... :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This answer refers to everyday usage of the words, not necessary the biologically correct definition:**

To me as a native German speaker from South-Western Germany, ***Rettich* and *Radieschen* are two entirely different things** (and I am not sure I ever thought the two could be biologically related until this question just mentioned them together and thus hinted at a relationship).

**Rettich** is a [long, white thing](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rettich_2008-3-3.JPG) that is large enough so your fingers just reach around it when holding it in your hand. Among other uses, it is eaten by some people in small spiral-shaped slices with salt. Other than that, it seems to appear in dishes not so originally from Germany such as kimchi and some types of sushi.

**Radieschen** are [little, bite-sized pinkish-red balls](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:210704_radieschen-raphanus-sativus-marktware_1-640x480.jpg) that are white on the inside. They are often sliced and added to salad or eaten on top of buttered bread.

Comment: While both are types of radish, I (personally) would use the Japanese loanword "daikon" to translate Rettich, since "radish" almost always refers to Radieschen in my experience.

Comment: Well, _Radi_ is a Southern synonym for _Rettich_ and _Radies+chen_ is a conventionalized diminutive.

Answer (score 2):

*Radieschen* are *garten-rettich*, garden rashishes, or in English, common radishes (*Raphanus sativus*), tart little red-skinned white spheres.  Sometimes, it is called the German radish.

*Rettiche* is a broad category of plants, *Brassicaceae*, that includes common radishes (even the large daikon or "Oriental radish" cultivar), rape-seed, cabbage, and turnips.

Comment: Small correction re: second paragraph: While _Rettiche_ is indeed a branch of the _Brassicaceae_ family, they form a relatively small part. Rape-seed, turnips, cabbages etc. are all *not* _Rettiche_!